# Why Injecting objects and making api calls in io() thread slows opening the Fragment?

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, viewmodel, dagger-2

In onAttach() of  VacationFragment I'm calling featuredDays() from VacationViewModel -> VacationRepository ,
what I notice when I'm clicking on view which navigates to VacationFragment, it opens with delays , I'm waiting for several millisecond till it opens the VacationFragment.
and when I'm commenting     vacationViewModel.featureDays(startDate,endDate) 
it opens the Fragment without delay

```
class MainApplication : Application(), HasActivityInjector, HasSupportFragmentInjector {
override fun onCreate() {
super.onCreate()
appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().androidModule(AndroidModule(this)).build()
appComponent.inject(this)
}

class VacationFragment : Fragment() {

   override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)
super.onAttach(context)
vacationViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity, icaViewModelFactory).get(VacationViewModel::class.java)
vacationViewModel.featureDays(startDate,endDate)}
 }

class VacationViewModel : ViewModel(), AppComponent.Injectable {

 private val disposables: CompositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

  @Inject
lateinit var vacationRepository: VacationRepository
 val featuredFeaturedCalendar: MediatorLiveData<FeaturedCalendar> = MediatorLiveData()

fun featureDays(from: String, till: String) {

val disposable = vacationRepository
    .featuredCalendar(from, till, KEY, ID)
    .map { featuredCalendar ->
      val holidays = arrayListOf<FeaturedCalendar.Holiday>()
      featuredCalendar.holidays.forEach { holidayItem ->
        val holiday = FeaturedCalendar.Holiday(format.parse(holidayItem.date), holidayItem.holiday)
        holidays.add(holiday)
      }
      FeaturedCalendar(featuredCalendar.status, holidays)
    }
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(mainThread())
    .subscribe(
        {
          featuredFeaturedCalendar.postValue(it)
        },
        {
          throw IllegalStateException(it)
        })

  disposables.add(disposable)
}}


class VacationRepository(private val apiDaysSeResource: ApiDaysSeResource) {

  fun featuredCalendar(from: String, till: String, key: String, id: String): Flowable<FeaturedCalendar> {
return apiDaysSeResource.days(from, till, key, id)//.toFlowable()
  }
```

}

```
public interface ApiDaysSeResource {
 Flowable<FeaturedCalendar> days(@Query("fran") String fran, @Query("till") String till, @Query("key") String key, @Query("id") String id);
}
```

Comment: A few possible reasons - 1. `map()` is happening on the origin thread, 2. `observeOn()` might be doing something really slow. Can disposable really be `null` after doing subscribe? Don't think you need that check.

Comment: @milosmns
I have removed the part of checking ,
If I comment the map() part and this line of code featuredFeaturedCalendar.postValue(it)
it the same, no difference

Comment: Hm. Okay then, perhaps it's the model that is somehow slow? Maybe your `onAttach()` does something that slows it down?

Comment: I have move the call of vacationViewModel.featureDays(startDate,endDate)
in onResume() .onCreate no difference,
but what do you think what is wrong  onAttach() ?

Comment: But If I remove the call of the method it is not slow ,it works as it should

Comment: I was just guessing with `onAttach()`, perhaps the injection became slow for some reason. So if you remove your `featureDays()` call, it's fast again?

Comment: Yes, and when I go back and navigate to that fragment it works fast as well.

Comment: I guess that the reason is the injection ,but how could it be solved?

Comment: Moved to chat. [Click here.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155708/discussion-between-milosmns-and-i-ss).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who won't be reading the full chat/comments section from the OP - the issue was with the `ApiDaysSeResource` class, its creation takes a lot of time to finish. As injections happen synchronously in `onAttach()`, the slowdown is therefore evident at startup. From the tests OP did, it seems that the slowdown was **1.0 - 1.5 seconds**, which is a lot.

If you have some spare time, I wrote a lengthy post about this issue and how to asynchronously inject singletons when you don't have access to the constructor that takes a long time time to finish. [Click here](http://angrybyte.me/post/165932263995/asyngletons-pt1) to read the article.

The basic idea is to inject an `Observable<YourSlowThing>` instead of `YourSlowThing` - that would allow you to wait for the instance to become available, but still get the non-null dependency at startup.